# check if EndExecuteNonQuery was successful

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 insComment.EndExecuteNonQuery();
```

Am trying to insert values into a database. What I need is to know if the code was succesfull then I display a success message.

```
if(insComment.EndExecuteNonQuery()){
show some message

}
```

Is that a workable option?

Comment: Do you need to do this asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

if the record is successfully inserted, then it will return 1 and you can prompt message accordingly

Should be like...

```
if(insComment.EndExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
  show some message
}
```

Comment: Should probably make that `>0` instead, OP didn't specify he was only inserting a single record..